# Projecting onto the unit $1$-ball

Tags: optimization, projection

Let $S := \left\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^d : \| x \|_1 \leq 1 \right\}$. For any point $y \in \mathbb{R}^d$, compute the projection of $y$ onto set $S$.

---

My intuition is just to scale down every element of $y = (y_1, y_2, \dots, y_d)$ by some factor such that $\sum_{i=1}^d |y_i| = 1$. Does this make sense? How do we prove this rigorously?

Comment: By projection, you mean the Euclidean projection using $\min \Vert \cdot \Vert_2$?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Yes

Comment: There are general methods to project a point on a polyhedron like [this](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Mario_Arioli/publication/256192604_Numerical_computation_of_the_projection_of_a_point_onto_a_polyhedron/links/02e7e51dea852c55f8000000/Numerical-computation-of-the-projection-of-a-point-onto-a-polyhedron.pdf). As we're in a simpler case here there maybe simpler methods... Project the point on each bounding hyperplane and make deductions from there??? Already the case $d=2$ leads to $8$ possibilities!

Comment: [Here](https://lcondat.github.io/publis/Condat_simplexproj.pdf) is a technique that works well in practice

Comment: Numerically????

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2327504/339790)

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2142180/339790)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you know the "projection theorem"?

It states that for a nonempty closed and convex subset $C$ of $\mathbb{R}$ there exists a unique vector that minimizes the distance between a point $z \in \mathbb{R}$ over $C$, the unique minimizer is called the projection of $z$ in $C$.

So basically, you have to solve the minimization problem $$ \min_{x \in C} ||z-x||^2_2.$$
For this you can use for example Lagrange Multiplier.

For example for $d = 2$ we have the following Lagrange function:
$$ L(x,\lambda) = (z_1 - x_1)^2 + (z_2 - x_2)^2 - \lambda \left( |x_1| + |x_2| - 1 \right) $$
Looking at the derivatives we get
$$ \frac{\partial L}{\partial x_i} = -2(z_i - x_i) - \lambda \frac{x_i}{|x_i|} \overset{!}{=} 0$$
and
$$ \frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda} = - |x_1| - |x_2| +1  \overset{!}{=} 0$$
Basically, you will get a candidate for the minimizer but also a candidate for a maximizer (the point at the opposite side). But you can easily verify which one is the minimizer and maximizer by inserting the value into the expression $||z-x||^2_2$ and for that I would also refer to this post: [Lagrange Min or Max](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2076766/how-to-know-whether-lagrange-multipliers-gives-maximum-or-minimum)

So what is with the special case if coordinate $i$ of $z$ is equal to zero?
This will lead to the fact, that
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_i} = 2x_i - \lambda \frac{x_i}{|x_i|} = 0$$ This leads to $x_i = 0$. Than we can insert this condition into the last one and get a condition about the length of the other coordinates and than you can insert them into the other equations. But you still have to consider that $x_j$ can be positive or negative.

Since we are only looking for critical points, we have to check also the points where we do not have differentiability: [Link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57859/generalizing-lagrange-multipliers-to-use-the-subdifferential)

Another way is to use the subgradient, [like here](https://angms.science/doc/CVX/Proj_l1.pdf). This document suggests also another way to solve the problem.

Comment: $L(x, \lambda) = (x_1 - z_1)^2 + (x_2 - z_2)^2 + \dots + (x_n - z_n)^2 - \lambda(|x_1| + |x_2| + \dots + |x_n| - 1)$ Is this a correct formulation of the Lagrange Multiplier problem?

Comment: Yes if you are considering $\min_{x \in C} ||z-x||^2_2$ which is equivalent to your case.

Comment: If you want to calculate it, I think it is the easiest to look at the case where $d = 2$. -> edited the post

Comment: @Tobias I don't think that this will work as $L(x,\lambda)$ is not differentiable, as $x \mapsto \vert x \vert$ is not at zero.

Comment: I'm also having some troubles with this solution. How do I find $\lambda, x_1, x_2$?

Comment: Ok that is correct, that I did not thought about the differentiability. But you could easily think about different cases, like when is $x_1$ positive or negative and so on.

Comment: I think the subgradient link you gave really helped since it had most of the details I was looking for. Thanks!